# Contornar o erro "propriedade de objeto não existe"

Tags: propriedade, angular-5

estou com o seguinte problema, sempre na hora de tratar o resultado da requisição `http` no `subscribe` aponta erros dizendo que a propriedade **x** não existe em `result`

```
return this.http.get('url').subscribe(result => {
    if (result.error) { // faça alguma coisa };
});
```

mas de fato existe a propriedade `error` porem ela só ira aparecer quando eu fizer a requisição! mas não entendi a lógica desse erro, e toda vez que tendo compilar o projeto da erro, ai preciso comentar as linhas de todas as funções que fazem operação com os `result`, compilo o programa, funciona, retiro o comentário ele continua funcionando normal, não sei se é bug do angular ou eu que estou fazendo algo errado, como escapar desse problema? não sei tbm se é culpa do visual studio code que tem umas diretivas do tipo: `// tslint:disable-next-line:component-class-suffix` que remove marcações de erro etc, enfim, alguma ideia?

Comment: Você deve tipar a resposta, ou atribuir o result em uma variável de tipo any antes de acessar a propriedade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Causa do problema

De acordo com a seção [*Type-checking the response*](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response) da documentação oficial do *framework*:

> The `HttpClient.get()` method parse the JSON server response into the
>   anonymous `Object` type. It doesn't know what the shape of that object
>   is.

Traduzindo:

> O método `HttpClient.get()` analisa a resposta do servidor JSON e a transforma no tipo anônimo `Object`. Ele não sabe qual é a forma desse objeto.

Isso significa que você não consegue acessar as propriedades de tal objeto usando a notação de ponto, a menos que você especifique explicitamente o tipo da resposta.

---

#### Solução 1

Utilize a notação de colchetes para extrair os valores.

```js
return this.http.get('url').subscribe(result => {
    if (result['error']) { // faça alguma coisa };
});
```

#### Solução 2

Diga ao `HttpClient` o tipo da resposta para tornar o consumo da saída mais fácil e mais óbvio.

Primeiro, defina uma interface com o formato correto:

```js
export interface Resposta {
    error: string;
    // defina propriedades adicionais abaixo
}
```

Então, especifique essa interface como o tipo sendo retornado por `HttpClient.get()`.

```js
return this.http.get<Resposta>('url').subscribe(result => {
    if (result.error) { // faça alguma coisa };
});
```

#### Solução 3

Utilize o tipo genérico `any`.

```js
return this.http.get('url').subscribe((result: any) => {
    if (result.error) { // faça alguma coisa };
});
```

Comment: solução perfeita! obrigado! `(result: any)`